# Swift next button change textfield

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have an app built with Swift and iOS8. In my `ViewController` I had two textfields.

**I use this code:**

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.textfield_A {
        self.textfield_B.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.textfield_B {
        self.textfield_B.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

**The effect:**

I select `textfield_A` and Press the *Next Button* -> the cursor jump to `textfield_B`

On `textfield_B` I press the *Done Button* -> the keyboard will be hidden.

All works fine.

But now I have made a change and the code doesn't work like this anymore.

I changed the `textfield_A` to a `textView`.

Any idea how I have to modify my code?

Comment: `textField `  and `textView ` both are different.

Comment: textfield delegate...wont be called for textview. Both are two different Class  and have different protocols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`textFieldShouldReturn` won't be called anymore for textfield_A now because is is a textview now, not a textfield.

Try adding this function

```
func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldChangeTextInRange: NSRange, replacementText: NSString!) -> Bool {
    if(replacementText == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to add an extension, this is the extension for swift **3.0**

```
extension UITextField {
class func connectFields(fields:[UITextField]) -> Void {
    guard let last = fields.last else {
        return
    }
    for i in 0 ..< fields.count - 1 {
        fields[i].returnKeyType = .next
        fields[i].addTarget(fields[i+1], action: #selector(UIResponder.becomeFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
    }
    last.returnKeyType = .done
    last.addTarget(last, action: #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
    }
}
```

and after you add this line of code:

```
UITextField.connectFields(fields: [field1, field2, field3])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both textfield then below code might be helpful to you my friend

Make sure your text fields have their delegate set and implement the textFieldShouldReturn method. This is the method that is called when the user taps the return key (no matter what it looks like).

The method might look something like this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.field1 {
        self.field2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```

And do not forget to give Delegate

```
TextField.delegate = self
```

Comment: Please read whole question. Code is working fine but the OP change the textfield to textview.

Comment: is it compulsory to use another as a textView ?

Comment: It's not compulsory, but you have to answer based on OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `textField` you can detect return key press by using `textFieldShouldReturn:` method. `textView` is a multi-line input so return key just adds a new line, so the easiest way to catch return key press is to implement `UITextViewDelegate` method:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way in your doneButton action:

```
@IBAction func donePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if textV.resignFirstResponder() {      //check if cursor is at textView.
        textfield_B.becomeFirstResponder() //move it to your next textField.
    } else  {         
        textfield_B.resignFirstResponder() //else hide your keyboard.
    }
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

This is a More Generic Solution you  can use this code with any amount of TextFields.
Just inherit **UITextFieldDelegate** and update the **Textfield Tag** according to the order

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let txtTag:Int = textField.tag

    if let textFieldNxt = self.view.viewWithTag(txtTag+1) as? UITextField {
        textFieldNxt.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else{
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```